# finding the reason for being disconnected from wifi network

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, netsh

I am behind a firewall known  as Sophos. I use Windows 10.
I am facing some challenges in my Windows 10 I am getting frequently disconnected from my wifi .
 .There are power outages in my network but apart from that why is it happening that I am not able to understand.
Upon some googling etc I came to conclusion may be power management of my USB wifi adapter could be a reason for this.
See the [screenshot](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/fb585163-8971-4b7a-8cd0-5bf8b1fd9e53?upload=true)
[image] 
So now I have disabled power management i.e. unticked allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.
What else should I check because there is a maximum login limit in my network i.e. if I exceed login to a certain number of times then I am disabled to login for the day.
Here is another [screenshot.](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/d83691f3-0ded-44ec-8a7a-c9ff2bca834d?upload=true)
[image]
I generated a detailed report of my wifi based on instructions available [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/generate-wlan-report-windows)
netsh wlan show wlanreport
report is available in %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\WlanReport\wlan-report-latest.html

I am trying to post complete HTML file it is a long long file and it has correctly identified the reason for my wifi disconnections.
The main reason as per the report for disconnections in past 3 days are following

> Reason                                           Count
>
> The driver disconnected while associating.      47 times
>
> The network is disconnected by the driver.     40 times
>     The network is disconnected by the user.     36 times 
>    The driver disconnected.                      1 
>    The operation was cancelled.                    1

Rest it is a very detailed  report of 544 pages.
My wireless adapter is

> Interface:D-Link DWA-131 Wireless N Nano USB Adapter(rev.E) Disconnect
>   Reason:Unknown Disconnect Reason:The network is disconnected by the
>   driver. Disconnect Reason:The driver disconnected while associating.
>   Disconnect Reason:The operation was cancelled.

For the interface  (on board wificard which I don't use)

> Interface:Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter Disconnect
>   Reason:The network is disconnected by the driver.

I do not use the onboard wifi card so there is no network.

So then I checked device drivers of my wireless system.

I have 2 wifi adapters.
This is for the first one 
[snapshot3](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/c189988b-1231-4b58-8efa-7c9c38defe7d?upload=true)
[image]
[snapshot4](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/c5098c61-8bad-4000-9a8e-a294bc0a99f2?upload=true)[image]

In the report main reasons I identified are 
Interface:D-Link DWA-131 Wireless N Nano USB Adapter(rev.E)
Disconnect Reason:Unknown
Disconnect Reason:The network is disconnected by the driver.
Disconnect Reason:The driver disconnected while associating.
Disconnect Reason:The operation was cancelled.

nterface:Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
Disconnect Reason:The driver disconnected while associating. (multiple entries)
Disconnect Reason:The network is disconnected by the driver.  (multiple entries)
Disconnect Reason:The network is disconnected by the user.

I updated the realtek wifi adaptor drivers.

[Screenshot6](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/52285516-380f-4391-b54b-55f1a94369e9?upload=true)
[Screenshot7](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/e607c173-70f5-4a65-aa20-d7669bfe84f7?upload=true)
[Screenshot8](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/229e8239-40fa-478b-a383-c9e5b6f2ee60?upload=true)
[image]

Any how looking at Windows update it does not seem to be any significant thing that I am missing.

There is a big detailed report html format in case any one wants to see let me know how can I post it online it is 594 pages. How do I post the complete report here.So now what more options I am left with to check?
There are frequent power outages in my network.So I am not sure the error codes mentioned above 
in netsh wlan show wlanreport 
 what do they signify? are these disconnections due to power failures(which is there) but then there are other error codes also mentioned in report. How do I get into details of these?

I am on a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: When you are connected, do you have slow (for your connection) download speed but normal (for your connection) upload speed? What happens if you disable bluetooth?

Comment: Bluetooth is always disabled and the problems you mentioned don't exist as far as current situation is but if you want to give some link to read then please do give I keep reading such things.

Answer (score -1):

I  think I've figured out this issue after struggling for few months. The issue for me atleast seems to be the wifi channel where my wifi router was configured in 13 and there were many people mentioning issues with channel 12,13 in windows 10. So do change the wifi channel and let me know. LIKE THIS AND LET OTHERS KNOW AS I DONT WANT OTHERS TO FEEL THE WAY I FELT REGARDING THIS ISSUE.

Comment: The ability or inability of your computer to connect to a given channel is dependent on the hardware and drivers provided by the manufacturer of that hardware. It is not dependent on the OS. While switching channels may be the solution for some, your post lacks information on HOW to do this and contains opinion, likely inaccurate, for the reasons why.